# fsolve gives TypeError: fsolve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x0'

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to numerically solve an equation that cannot be solved analiticaly (solution must depend on k). But using fsolve gives me TypeError

```
from scipy import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

k=linspace(0,1)
fsolve(lambda x,k: log(x)/log(k))**k-x**(1/arctanh(k), np.array([[0], [1]]))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e6764ec01b24> in <module>
----> 1 fsolve(lambda x,k: log(x)/log(k))**k-x**(1/arctanh(k), np.array([[0], [1]]))

TypeError: fsolve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x0'
```

Comment: I think you may be having parentheses issues. `fsolve(lambda x,k: log(x)/log(k))` is a complete statement. Is that the intended functionality?

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to do. I suggest you re-write your function using the `def` way (which should help you better debug) and you need to refer to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).